# Can't access a specific property in a JavaScript Array of objects Using a Lambda Function with Node JS

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

// I can access the AccountSite property from other handlers/functions in the file using loops except in that function. I can get all Other properties using loops in the function except that one.

//  I have tried My code in visual studio using console.log  for debugging instead of Say(in Alexa) and I can have access to the property with the exact code except for that change.

```
const Data = [{
    AccountName: "Jhon Doe ",
    Phone: "353262",
    Website: "something.com",
    AccountSite: "Random Name",
    Description: "Random Description",
    AccountOwner: "Jhondoe@yahoo.com"
  },
{
    AccountName: "Jane Doe ",
    Phone: "353223462",
    Website: "something2.com",
    AccountSite: "Random Name2",
    Description: "Random Description2",
    AccountOwner: "Janedoe@yahoo.com"
  },{
    AccountName: "Susan Doe ",
    Phone: "353232462",
    Website: "something3.com",
    AccountSite: "Random Name3",
    Description: "Random Description3",
    AccountOwner: "susandoe@yahoo.com"
  },
];

const getAccounSite_Handler = {

//handler code
//handler code
//handler code

let say;

Data.map(pos => {
 say= ` ${pos.AccountSite}`;   //if I put pos.Propertyname it would give me the property for the last object in the array for the other propert name except accountsite

// Account site is accessible in this handler if I don't use a loop

//have tried for loop and map 

//have a very similar code for another skill but it is working; it is accessing the properties


//end of the handler

}


When I run Alexa it says  "There was a problem with the requested skill's response" when the handler is called
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to make Alexa, to read all AccountSites? The code you have written right now always reassigns `say` on each loop instance. If you want to build a list of values and store it in variable `say` your code should look like this:

```
let say = '';

Data.forEach(pos => {
   say += `${pos.AccountSite} `;
});
```

I tested it using your data and got the result that say is equal to:

```
"Random Name Random Name2 Random Name3 "
```

Is this is the result you wanted?